# Replication of Form method with loadOneTab

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-restartless

If I dynamically insert a form object into a page, submit and remove the form and it works fine.

Here is an example of the form code:

```
<form target="_blank" enctype="multipart/form-data" 
      action="https://www.example.com/" method="POST">
  <input value="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" name="image_content" type="hidden">
  <input value="" name="filename" type="hidden">
  <input value="" name="image_url" type="hidden">
</form>
```

When I try to do the same process with `loadOneTab()`, result `POST` is not exactly the same and therefore the result is not the same as above.
On checking the headers, "some value" is not sent fully (gets cropped) and it sets `Content-Length: 0`.
I must be missing something.

```
let postStream = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/network/mime-input-stream;1']
                   .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIMIMEInputStream);
postStream.addHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
postStream.addHeader('filename', '');
postStream.addHeader('image_url', '');
postStream.addHeader('image_content', 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==');
postStream.addContentLength = true;
window.gBrowser.loadOneTab('https://www.example.com/',
    {inBackground: false, postData: postStream});
```

**Note:**  image_content value is 'data:image/png;base64' Data URI
NoScript causes issues with sending form and XSS and I prefer to use `loadOneTab` for the `inBackground`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, one would use `FormData` to compose the `postData` of a request, but unfortunately we cannot do so here, as there is currently no way to get the stream (and other information) from a `FormData` instance (`nsIXHRSendable` is not scriptable, unfortunately), so we'll have to create a `multipart/form-data` stream ourselves.

Since it is likely you'll want to post some file data as well, I added file uploads as well. ;)

```
function encodeFormData(data, charset) {
  let encoder = Cc["@mozilla.org/intl/saveascharset;1"].
                createInstance(Ci.nsISaveAsCharset);
  encoder.Init(charset || "utf-8",
               Ci.nsISaveAsCharset.attr_EntityAfterCharsetConv + 
               Ci.nsISaveAsCharset.attr_FallbackDecimalNCR,
               0);
  let encode = function(val, header) {
    val = encoder.Convert(val);
    if (header) {
      val = val.replace(/\r\n/g, " ").replace(/"/g, "\\\"");
    }
    return val;
  }

  let boundary = "----boundary--" + Date.now();
  let mpis = Cc['@mozilla.org/io/multiplex-input-stream;1'].
             createInstance(Ci.nsIMultiplexInputStream);
  let item = "";
  for (let k of Object.keys(data)) {
    item += "--" + boundary + "\r\n";
    let v = data[k];
    if (v instanceof Ci.nsIFile) {
      let fstream = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/file-input-stream;1"].
                    createInstance(Ci.nsIFileInputStream); 
      fstream.init(v, -1, -1, Ci.nsIFileInputStream.DEFER_OPEN);
      item += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + encode(k, true) + "\";" +
              " filename=\"" + encode(v.leafName, true) + "\"\r\n";
      let ctype = "application/octet-stream";
      try {
        let mime = Cc["@mozilla.org/mime;1"].getService(Ci.nsIMIMEService);
        ctype = mime.getTypeFromFile(v) || ctype;
      }
      catch (ex) {
        console.warn("failed to get type", ex);
      }
      item += "Content-Type: " + ctype + "\r\n\r\n";
      let ss = Cc["@mozilla.org/io/string-input-stream;1"].
               createInstance(Ci.nsIStringInputStream);
      ss.data = item;
      mpis.appendStream(ss);
      mpis.appendStream(fstream);
      item = "";
    }
    else {
      item += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + encode(k, true) + "\"\r\n\r\n";
      item += encode(v);
    }
    item += "\r\n";
  }
  item += "--" + boundary + "--\r\n";
  let ss = Cc["@mozilla.org/io/string-input-stream;1"].
           createInstance(Ci.nsIStringInputStream);
  ss.data = item;
  mpis.appendStream(ss);
  let postStream = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/mime-input-stream;1"].
                   createInstance(Ci.nsIMIMEInputStream);
  postStream.addHeader("Content-Type",
                       "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
  postStream.setData(mpis);
  postStream.addContentLength = true;
  return postStream;
}
```

(You could use additional `nsIMIMEInputStream` instead of string-concatenating stuff together, but this would perform worse and has no real merit).

Which can then be used like e.g.:

```
let file = Services.dirsvc.get("Desk", Ci.nsIFile);
file.append("australis-xp hällow, wörld.png");

let postData = encodeFormData({
  "filename": "",
  "image_url": "",
  "image_content": "--somne value ---",
  "contents": file
}, "iso8859-1");

gBrowser.loadOneTab("http://www.example.org/", {
  inBackground: false,
  postData: postData
});
```

Comment: Tnx Nils. I was using the first one to send base64 image data. As you guessed, my next step would have been file upload. It looks like a lot more work than inserting a `Form` into document. BTW, I am now part of #amo-editors (I haven't seen you logged in the IRC)

Comment: @erosman and nmaier how what is the value of `image_content`? Is it data url obtained from canvas so like `'image_content': document.getElementById("canvas").toDataURL()`?

Comment: @Noitidart In my example, `'image_content'` was base64/Image src Data:URL, direct from img src (not from canvas) example: (the cat) http://dopiaza.org/tools/datauri/examples/index.php

Comment: Oh I see @erosman so you like XHR load the image and then base64 encode that and pass that

Comment: @Noitidart .. not at all ... `img` `src` is already `data:image/png;base64` and I want to `POST` this `src` to another page

Comment: Nils: How can I pass `formData` to `postData`?

Comment: If you mean `FormData`, then you cannot. I covered that in the intro paragraph of my answer.

Comment: Man I'm getting a blob from a canvas, with toBlob, then I use FileReader to get array buffer, and I try to attach it in, for small images it works, but for big images (like > 200px x 200px) something is going wrong. This was what I was doing - can you please take a look - https://discourse.mozilla-community.org/t/post-arraybuffer-to-loadonetab/6224