# How to pass formData to postData in loadOneTab?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-restartless

I have a `formData` object and would like to pass it to `loadOneTab()`

Example:

```
var formData = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/files/formdata;1']
                .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMFormData);
formData.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
formData.append('filename', '');
formData.append('image_url', URL);
```

How can I pass above object to `postData`

```
window.gBrowser.loadOneTab('https://www.example.com/',
    {inBackground: false, postData: postStream});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I already kinda answered this as part of your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25020668/484441).

Unfortunately we cannot use `FormData` here, as there is currently no way to get the stream (and other information) from a FormData instance (`nsIXHRSendable` is not scriptable, unfortunately). `postData` however expects the value to be an `nsIInputStream` instance.

So there is no way to use `FormData` in conjunction with `loadOneTab` and friends (essentially all `<tabbrowser>` and `<browser>` methods expect a stream if they accept a `postData` argument).

Comment: Thank you Nils. I will post another question, trying another approach